# Derivative of the Chern-Simons form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory, chern-simons-theory

I want to verify the relation of the Chern-Simons form
$$ d \,  \text{tr}  (AdA+ \frac{2}{3} AAA) = \text{tr} FF$$
where $\omega \mu\equiv \omega \wedge \mu$ and $F=dA+AA$.
Using the property $d\, \text{tr}(\dots) = \text{tr} D(\dots)$, where $D$ is the covariant derivative so that $DF=0$ and for $\omega$ in the adjoint $D\omega=d\omega+[A,\omega]$ (which implies $DA=dA$), I find:

- for the first term,
  $$d\, \text{tr}AdA=\text{tr} (DAdA-ADdA)=\text{tr} (dAdA-A[A,dA])=\text{tr} (dAdA-AAdA+AdAA)=\text{tr} (dAdA-2dA AA)$$
  where I used $d^2 A=0$, $d(\omega \mu) = d\omega \mu+(-1)^{p}\omega d\mu$,the definition $[\omega, \mu]= \omega \mu - (-1)^{pq} \mu \omega$ and $\text{tr} \omega  \mu = (-1)^{pq} \text{tr}\mu\omega$ ($p,q$ are the rank of the forms $\omega,\mu$).
- for the second term I have
  $$\frac{2}{3}\text{tr}(DA AA - ADAA+AADA)= 2 \text{tr}dA AA$$
  where again I used the properties mentioned before.

Putting everything together, so

$$d \, \text{tr}(AdA+\frac{2}{3}AAA)= tr{dAdA}$$
which is not the correct result, since
$$\text{tr}FF=\text{tr}(dA+AA)(dA+AA)= \text{tr}(dAdA+2dAAA)$$
from $\text{tr}AAAA=0$. Where am I wrong? I cannot find the error, but my result must not be correct. I am using the notation of Baez & Muniain: https://doi.org/10.1142/2324. A sketch of the calculation is given on page 285.

$\textbf{EDIT}$: SOLVED. The problem was the assumption $[A,A]=0$, while instead this is not true. In fact in this way $DA=dA+2AA$ and all the terms combine nicely in the well-known formula. An alert for who uses the book by Baez: do not trust every formula they throw to you...

Answer (score 1):

Because everything is inside a trace, I will omit it for clarity and specify it when needed.

1. The first term is simple
   \begin{equation}
   d(A\wedge dA) = dA \wedge dA
   \end{equation} because as you stated $d^2=0$
2. Next,
   \begin{equation}
   d(A \wedge A \wedge A) = [dA^a \wedge (A \wedge A)^b - (A \wedge dA)^a \wedge A^b + (A \wedge A)^a \wedge dA^b]T_a T_b
   \end{equation} using $d$ of a wedge product like you stated. Now, I've written it explicitly in terms of the generators as the connection is Lie algebra-valued.
   Now we make use of $Tr([T_a, T_b])=0$ such that we can switch the generators as we want, resulting in
   \begin{equation}
   d(A \wedge A \wedge A) = 3 A \wedge A \wedge dA
   \end{equation}
   Putting together what we have so far (still within a trace)
   \begin{equation}
   dA \wedge dA + 2 A \wedge A \wedge dA = (F + A \wedge A) \wedge dA
   \end{equation}
   The LHS was the final expression you stated.
   Finally, substitute $dA = F - A \wedge A$ in this expression such that
   we indeed find $F \wedge F$ after the disappearance of the trace of $A \wedge A \wedge A \wedge A$.

Note that I never used $DF = 0$, because this would already be using the equation of motion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, by expliciting the Lie algebra generators is clear. I think I found my error: I was using $[A,A]=0$ as given in the textbook I mentioned. However this is not consitent with the very formula of the commutator that they give, since $[A,A]=AA-(-1)^1 AA =2AA$ since $A$ is a 1-form. So the error was trusting the book!

Comment: If the commutator were zero, then you would be working with an Abelian gauge group like U(1) where $F = dA$. Maybe the book used that $Tr [A,A] = 0 $ because of $Tr [T_a, T_b] = 0$?

Comment: Why does $Tr(A^A^A^A)=0$?

Comment: We are working in three dimensions, so any differential form of dimension 4 or higher is trivial since $\Omega^{p>3}(M)$ is empty. Since $A$ is a one-form, $A \wedge A \wedge A \wedge A \in \Omega^{4}(M)$ and therefore has to vanish. It's indeed misleading that I wrote that the trace has to vanish while it's actually the whole wedge product.

Comment: @Guliano Sorry I ask a lot, but, why in step 2 do we need to use the generators and not just use the standard formula for the differential of a wedge product:  $d(\omega\wedge\eta)= d\omega \wedge\eta+(-1)^{kl}\omega\wedge d\eta$ for $\omega$ and $\eta$, $k$ and $l$ forms respectively. Doing that I get the same result $3A\wedge A\wedge dA$. (Also I think there is an error in the left part of this equation).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. Need to think for a bit... What you wrote is right and I essentially used the same property. If I remember correctly, since the differential forms are Lie algebra-valued you have to be careful when switching factors in the wedge product because a commutator of the generators will appear as well: $A \wedge A = (A^a \wedge A^b) T_a T_b = - A^b \wedge A^a (T_b T_a + [T_a, T_b]) = - A \wedge A - A^b \wedge A^a i f_{ab}^c T_c$. Note that in the Abelian case we would have $A \wedge A = 0$.