Trouble showing $Tr(F \wedge F) = dQ_3$
I had a bit of difficulty with taking the exterior derivative of the $$Tr (\frac{2}{3} (A \wedge A \wedge A)$$  in the Chern-Simons 3-form $Q_3$ to show that this gives a $2 Tr(dA \wedge A)$ term in $$Tr( dQ_3) = Tr(F\wedge F).$$
ChatGPT was a bit self contradictory in that while it says that $$ d (A \wedge A \wedge A) =  dA \wedge A \wedge A - A \wedge dA \wedge A + A \wedge A \wedge dA$$
(where presumably the minus sign in the second term comes about because $A$ is $$d(A \wedge A) = dA \wedge A - A \wedge dA$$ because $A$ is a one-form),
it then claims that $$Tr d (A \wedge A \wedge A)  = 3 Tr (dA \wedge A \wedge A).$$
The factor of 3 does seem to be what's needed for $$Tr( dQ_3) = Tr(F\wedge F)$$ to hold. I am puzzled about what happened to the minus sign in $- A \wedge dA \wedge A$.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688632/

chatGPT self contradictory? a bit? lol that is the usual behaviour of that dumb bot.

Hint: The minus sign comes from that the 1-form $A$ and the 3-form $dA \wedge A$ anti-commute under the trace symbol.

$$Q_3 = Tr \left[ A \wedge F - \frac{1}{3} A \wedge A \wedge A \right] , \qquad F  = {\text d}  A + A \wedge A $$
Then,
$$
{\text d} Q_3 = Tr[{\text d} A \wedge F - A \wedge {\text d}  F -  {\text d}  A \wedge A \wedge A]
$$
We now use the fact that ${\text d} F+ A \wedge F - F \wedge A = 0$ so that
\begin{align}
{\text d} Q_3 &= Tr[{\text d}  A \wedge F + A \wedge A \wedge F - A \wedge F \wedge A -  {\text d}  A \wedge A \wedge A] \\
&= Tr[ F \wedge F - A \wedge A \wedge A \wedge A ]
\end{align}
The final step is to prove that $Tr[  A \wedge A \wedge A \wedge A ] = 0$ (HW).
